# Moving Keys in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

This is my first question, I've read the good posting guide but if I make any mistakes please let me know.

So anyway, I have a dictionary in python that is has keys numbered 1,2,3,4,5, etc and my question is if I delete, say 3, so I have 1,2,4,5 can I change the keys for 4,5 so they become 3,4?

Something like:

```
mydict = {1:'bob', 2:'sue', 3:'joe', 4:'mary', 5:'billy'}

del mydict[1]

mydict[3] = mydict[4]
mydict[4] = mydict[5]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yes you can, have you got any error ?

Comment: You could just try this, short answer yes and it works

Comment: I had a `KeyError: '2'` but I suspect that is just bad declaration on my part after reviewing my code

Comment: Note that this will currently leave `mydict[5]` in place, which may not be the desired behaviour.

Comment: @Jim none of the code you've posted affects `mydict[2]`, so it must be something else.

Comment: You might reconsider using a dict at all. If you want a collection whose items can be individually accessed using an integer index, and you want the indices to automatically "move down" when you remove an item, then why not just use a list?

Comment: What about the existing key value pair for key 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, where n is the value you wish to remove, for example 3:

```
dict(zip(range(1, len(mydict) + 1), [j for j in mydict.values() if j != mydict[n]]))
```